# Spinoff / Alternate Universe of DC Comics involving mother earth rising up?

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, parallel-universe

I'm looking for a spinoff/alternate universe version of DC comics. I don't remember all the details but I do remember that the big Justice League members (Batman, Superman, Wonder Woman) are all dead. The heroes that are present (they have the same powers but don't really share the same designs) are the Flash and Green Lantern along with a few others, but they have new / different backstories (the Flash inherits the powers of the god Mercury as he's dying, and Green Lantern gets his powers by being blessed by the Earth somehow?). If it helps, the color palette was a bit more muted and greyed out than in a lot of other comics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [*Earth 2*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Earth_2_Vol_1).

Superman, Wonder-Woman and Batman are killed fighting Parademons. Mercury passes on his powers to Jay Garrick (the Flash) and Alan Scott (Green Lantern) is chosen by the Earth Spirit as her champion.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like it's it. Thanks!